# I need to associate multiple docs to list items when item is created. Need to function similar to attachments

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, list-item

I need my users to be able to associate multiple documents to list items they create. I don't think I can use attachments though since each document needs to have a 'type' (eg. they need to upload a request doc, review doc, approval doc, etc). I need for them to be able to 'attach' these docs when the list item is created. I was thinking to add a document library web part to the 'newform.aspx' page where they could upload relevant docs, but then I am not able to associate the docs they upload to that item. Please see the image below for what I need my form to look like. The top part is the new item form (stylized) and the bottom part would be the 'attachments'. I can't see any way to use actual attachments (no doc lib items) and associate them as certain doc types (eg review doc, approval doc, etc). I need to make a view that has the item and its relevant 'attached' docs. I can use REST as well, but I couldn't think of way to accomplish that either. Any ideas? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look into Document Sets - that's exactly what they were designed for. Would those work for you?

Create a new content type based on the default 'document set' content type, and add any columns you need. It will act like a 'list' item even though it's really a folder.

You can define document templates to be created when they create the new document set.

Sometimes document sets can be a pain in the neck but it gets you most of the way there.